# Has anyone ever built a tool that archives static lib dependencies into a static lib that references them?

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, archive

I know you can AR (macOS/Linux) or /OUT: lib1.lib lib2.lib (Windows) the entire archive but it seems a rather crude approach.

I presume you could manually script the addition of object files into your static lib but that seems very error prone.

Basically I am building a static lib that uses a static lib of cryptopp (technically it doesn't use it, but it does introduce those dependencies into any client that links with my lib) - and I would like to make things simpler for people using my SDK and simply provide them with a single static library to link against.

Like I mentioned above, I can just AR/OUT the whole cryptopp lib into my static lib but that seems incredibly wasteful for the small about of object references I actually need.

I must be missing something...

Is there a tool for doing this?

Comment: ***Is there a tool for doing this?*** I have not seen one with that said software requests are off topic at StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "technically it doesn't use it, but it does introduce those dependencies into any client that links with my lib"!?

Comment: @drescherjm - You can't ask about tools in development systems?  Questions about AR would then be off topic?  I'm basically asking if I'm missing some way to do this with existing development tools.  Basically I'm trying to do something I've never done before, and I suspect someone else has solved this problem; ergo, I'm looking to experts here to help.  I'm not asking someone to write a tool. Apologies if that was unclear.

Comment: @WernerHenze - By that I meant that libraries are simply archives of object files containing definitions and a static library doesn't "use" another object defined elsewhere in the fashion that a client application does - it's more like jigsaw puzzle pieces that have a shape that only fits a certain definition and when linked into a client application they have to fit, then the client application actually makes use of the combined definitions.

Comment: If you want to hide the dependencies you could also use dynamic libraries.